# How do I shorten the name of a program for powershell

Tags: powershell

I just put sublime text into my path variable so whenever i have to edit a text while I'm in Powershell, I can type `sublime_text <file name.txt>` instead of `notepad <file name.txt>`

But writing out `sublime_text` is too long.
Is there a way I could shorten that and write, say `sublime <file name.txt>` and still have that txt file open in sublime text?

Comment: I'd recommend using VSCode. There you just need `code <file name.txt>`  ;-)

Comment: Create an alias using `New-Alias` or `Set-Alias`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wrapper function for this. You can also store the function in your [profile file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2) so it is auto-loaded each time you start a session.

```
function subl {
    $p = try { Convert-Path $args } catch  { }
    sublime_text $p
}
```

Things like this should work fine:

```
PS /> subl .
PS /> subl .\myscript.ps1
```